# Custom field are not showing devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%=f.label :name %></br>
    <%=f.text_field :name , autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%=f.label :User_type %></br>
    <%=f.select_tag (:user_type , option_for_select([["Manager",1],["developer",2],["creator",3]])), autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

above is my sign up devise form problem is that i add two new field in this name and user type but these two fields are not showing in the form on screen.....

Comment: Please show the devise initializer. Most probably you are not using Model-specific views.

Comment: thanks for reply. i find the solution which is add this line {config.scoped_views = true} in initializer and problem solve...